# Always errors when launch the navigation

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some serious errors when I start the navigation on turtlebot, but I have no idea how to solve that:

```
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/move_base/move_base: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libcostmap_2d.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPvNS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS7_S7_z
[move_base-15] process has died [pid 28518, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/move_base/move_base cmd_vel:=navigation_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel odom:=odom __name:=move_base __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/eef369be-a079-11e3-844d-0008cacd6165/move_base-15.log].log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/eef369be-a079-11e3-844d-0008cacd6165/move_base-15*.log

/opt/ros/hydro/lib/gmapping/slam_gmapping: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/gmapping/slam_gmapping: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPvNS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS7_S7_z
[slam_gmapping-12] process has died [pid 28282, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/gmapping/slam_gmapping scan:=scan __name:=slam_gmapping __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/eef369be-a079-11e3-844d-0008cacd6165/slam_gmapping-12.log].log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/eef369be-a079-11e3-844d-0008cacd6165/slam_gmapping-12*.log
```

Those errors are happened in a 32-bit ubuntu, but no errors in 64-bit ubuntu, why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134356/always-errors-when-launch-the-navigation/) by [Jianyuan Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/11541/jianyuan-ma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would check that your system is fully up-to-date by running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

If that doesn't help, I would take a look at this similar question: http://answers.ros.org/question/123421/hydro-kinect-ubuntu-1204-library-issue/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1